# Create smaller dataframes from a large dataframe using the index values from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list

```
a = [15, 50 , 75]
```

Using the above list I have to create smaller dataframes filtering out rows (the number of rows is defined by the list) on the index from the main dataframe.

let's say my main dataframe is **df**
the dataframes I'd like to have is **df1 (from row index 0-15),df2 (from row index 15-65), df3 (from row index 65 - 125)**

since these are just three I can easily use something like this below:

```
limit1 = a[0]
limit2 = a[1] + limit1
limit3 = a[2] + limit3

df1 = df.loc[df.index <= limit1]
df2 = df.loc[(df.index > limit1) & (df.index <= limit2)]
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop = True)
df3 =  df.loc[(df.index > limit2) & (df.index <= limit3)]
df3 = df3.reset_index(drop = True)
```

But what if I want to implement this with a long list on the main dataframe **df**, I am looking for something which is iterable like the following (which doesn't work):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index <= limit1]
for i in range(2,3):
 for j in range(2,3):
  for k in range(2,3):
   df[i] =  df.loc[(df.index > limit[j]) & (df.index <= limit[k])]
   df[i] = df[i].reset_index(drop=True)
   print(df[i])
```

Comment: According to your logic it should be from 0-15 , then from 15-65, and then from 65-90, else your rule is changing

Comment: Yes. That's correct

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could modify your code by building dataframes from the main dataframe iteratively cutting out slices from the end of the dataframe.

```
dfs = [] # this list contains your partitioned dataframes
a = [15, 50 , 75]
for idx in a[::-1]:
    dfs.insert(0, df.iloc[idx:])
    df = df.iloc[:idx]
dfs.insert(0, df) # add the last remaining dataframe
print(dfs)
```

Another option is to use list expressions as follows:

```
a = [0, 15, 50 , 75]
dfs = [df.iloc[a[i]:a[i+1]] for i in range(len(a)-1)]
```

Comment: on a 75 row dataframe this brings a 60 row df, then a 10 row df and then a 0 row df

Comment: Now it brings a 35 row, a 25 row and a 0 row df

Comment: 0-to-15 is missing. I would set: `a = [0, 15, 50 , 75]`

Comment: true. adding  dfs.insert(0, df) at the end solves it.

Answer (score 1):

This does it. It's better to use dictionaries if you want to store multiple variables and call them later. It's bad practice to create variables in an iterative way, so always avoid it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.linspace(1,75,75), columns=['a'])
a = [15, 50 , 25]
d = {}

b = 0
for n,i in enumerate(a):
    d[f'df{n}'] = df.iloc[b:b+i]
    b+=i
```

Output:

[image]